# WebGPU and white screen in different browsers

Tags: webgpu, chrome-canary

I installed chrome canery on my tablet to use webgpu with three.js. This also worked for some time after I activated webgpu in chrome://flags. Recently, however, I only get a white picture. So I looked for other browser. Google dev, it worked then, but after a while the white screen also came up when rendering. So I installed edge canary, it worked again, but after a while the white screen also came up when rendering.
I don't understand the phenomenon. Why does it work for a few days without problems and then not anymore? Anyone know the phenomenon?

Comment: It sounds like you're only using Chrome, so you'd probably have an easier time reporting the problem on their forums.

Comment: AFAIK WebGPU doesn't run on Android yet. It's in development so I'd expect it to break often. Chrome Canary is updated daily.

Comment: Chrome canary works on my android phone. I have the same chrome canary version on my android tablet: 117.0.5928.0 the webview version is also identical. The flags are identical. So i don't understand why i see the message in chrome canary: "your browser does not support webgpu yet" when I try to open webgpu apps.